# External LDAP SMIME Public Key Search Fails from Outlook for iOS With NoSuchObject

Tags: ldap, outlook, ios, smime

The Outlook for iOS documentation seems to indicate that it's possible to configure an external LDAP address to search for SMIME public key certificates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/outlook-for-ios-and-android/smime-outlook-for-ios-and-android#ldap-support-for-certificate-lookup

We have an external LDAP directory that works perfectly fine from Outlook for Windows clients as well as MaaS360's iOS email client.  When we try to specify that same directory using an Intune app configuration policy, we can see the directory in Outlook for iOS but attempts to send encrypted email fails with "invalid recipient detected" so apparently Outlook for iOS is unable to return the proper public key for the recipient.

Digging into the Outlook for iOS Service API logs, it looks like there is a successful bind but the search fails returning "NoSuchObject"  Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

```
<request>
  <AccountId>4352</AccountId>
  <LogTime>2023-09-21T00:48:00.875Z</LogTime>
  <RequestId>16589</RequestId>
  <RequestGuid>{992A7273-570B-F944-B00C-EAD372D5979F}</RequestGuid>
  <CommandId>LdapSearch</CommandId>
  <Tag>hx_8zv05k</Tag>
  <Username></Username>
  <Server>fakedirectory.contoso.com</Server>
  <Port>636</Port>
  <SslScheme>SecureFromStart</SslScheme>
  <Content>
    <BindRequest>
      <Tag>808464432</Tag>
      <RequestId>0</RequestId>
      <MessageId>1</MessageId>
      <LdapProtocolOp>BindRequest</LdapProtocolOp>
      <LdapVersion>3</LdapVersion>
      <Username></Username>
      <AuthenticationChoice>Simple</AuthenticationChoice>
    </BindRequest>
    <BindResponse>
      <Tag>808464432</Tag>
      <RequestId>0</RequestId>
      <MessageId>1</MessageId>
      <LdapProtocolOp>BindResponse</LdapProtocolOp>
      <LdapResult>
        <LdapResultCode>Success</LdapResultCode>
        <MatchedDN>Pii</MatchedDN>
        <DiagnosticMessage></DiagnosticMessage>
        <Referrals />
      </LdapResult>
    </BindResponse>
    <BindRequest>
      <Tag>808464432</Tag>
      <RequestId>0</RequestId>
      <MessageId>2</MessageId>
      <LdapProtocolOp>BindRequest</LdapProtocolOp>
      <LdapVersion>3</LdapVersion>
      <Username></Username>
      <AuthenticationChoice>Simple</AuthenticationChoice>
    </BindRequest>
    <BindResponse>
      <Tag>808464432</Tag>
      <RequestId>0</RequestId>
      <MessageId>2</MessageId>
      <LdapProtocolOp>BindResponse</LdapProtocolOp>
      <LdapResult>
        <LdapResultCode>Success</LdapResultCode>
        <MatchedDN>Pii</MatchedDN>
        <DiagnosticMessage></DiagnosticMessage>
        <Referrals />
      </LdapResult>
    </BindResponse>
    <SearchRequest>
      <Tag>4246338630</Tag>
      <RequestId>16589</RequestId>
      <MessageId>3</MessageId>
      <LdapProtocolOp>SearchRequest</LdapProtocolOp>
      <BaseObject>Pii</BaseObject>
      <Scope>WholeSubtree</Scope>
      <DerefAliases>DerefAlways</DerefAliases>
      <SizeLimit>0</SizeLimit>
      <TimeLimit>30</TimeLimit>
      <TypesOnly>0</TypesOnly>
      <Or>
        <EqualityMatch>
          <AttributeDescription>mail</AttributeDescription>
          <AssertionValue>Pii</AssertionValue>
        </EqualityMatch>
        <EqualityMatch>
          <AttributeDescription>rfc822Mailbox</AttributeDescription>
          <AssertionValue>Pii</AssertionValue>
        </EqualityMatch>
        <EqualityMatch>
          <AttributeDescription>mailNickName</AttributeDescription>
          <AssertionValue>Pii</AssertionValue>
        </EqualityMatch>
        <EqualityMatch>
          <AttributeDescription>sAMAccountName</AttributeDescription>
          <AssertionValue>Pii</AssertionValue>
        </EqualityMatch>
        <EqualityMatch>
          <AttributeDescription>proxyAddresses</AttributeDescription>
          <AssertionValue>Pii</AssertionValue>
        </EqualityMatch>
      </Or>
      <AttributeValues>
        <AttributeValue>Pii</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue>Pii</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue>Pii</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue>Pii</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue>Pii</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue>Pii</AttributeValue>
      </AttributeValues>
    </SearchRequest>
    <SearchResultDoneResponse>
      <Tag>808464432</Tag>
      <RequestId>0</RequestId>
      <MessageId>3</MessageId>
      <LdapProtocolOp>SearchResultDoneResponse</LdapProtocolOp>
      <LdapResult>
        <LdapResultCode>NoSuchObject</LdapResultCode>
        <MatchedDN>Pii</MatchedDN>
        <DiagnosticMessage></DiagnosticMessage>
        <Referrals />
      </LdapResult>
    </SearchResultDoneResponse>
    <LdapMessage>
      <Tag>808464432</Tag>
      <RequestId>0</RequestId>
      <MessageId>4</MessageId>
      <LdapProtocolOp>UnbindRequest</LdapProtocolOp>
    </LdapMessage>
  </Content>
  <Duration>315 msecs</Duration>
  <QuitTag>7bwka</QuitTag>
  <EndTag>c7n0o</EndTag>
  <StatusCode>NoSuchObject</StatusCode>
  <DisconnectReason>ServerClosed</DisconnectReason>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

A search query whose filter didn't match anything would still return `Success`, even if there were zero results.

`NoSuchObject`, on the other hand, means that the search *base* was nonexistent – the`<BaseObject>` pointed to a nonexistent entry so there was nowhere to even begin the search. (The response's `<MatchedDN>` would include the part of the DN that *did* match.)

Since the actual values were filtered out, you'll need to check your LDAP server's logs to figure out what base DN was submitted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  One thing I noticed was that the Intune configuration only has a field to specify the LDAP URL.  There is no field for specifying a search base.  If there is no ability to specify a search base, would the search just start at the top level of the tree?  I wondered if the fact that I can't enter a search base is causing the problem.

Comment: LDAP URLs can include a search base (`ldaps://host/base?attr,attr?scope?(filter)`). I don't know if Intune supports that, but it'd be the standard way to fit everything in one field. As for when the DN is not specified – not sure but I'd expect it to find your database's "top-level" DN from a rootDSE query, like would be typical for AD... but it *could* also be generating a domain-style `dc=...,dc=...` DN from your domain name instead, or it could indeed be using an empty DN.

Comment: The external LDAP we're dealing with is a non-Microsoft directory.  I have a ticket open with Microsoft support to troubleshoot why this won't work on Outlook for iOS but does work on Outlook for Windows.  So far MS hasn't been able to tell us what's going on so I was hoping to gain a better understanding of what should happen to help engage with them better.  If we can't get this working then our only alternative is to sync 100k+ contacts and public keys into our on-prem AD/O365 which is something we would much rather avoid. We don't manage the LDAP server so can't get the logs from there.

Comment: Our LDAP admin checked the logs and advised that there is no search base specified and this is the problem.

There is no way to specify a separate search base in Outlook for iOS. According to the RFC, an LDAP URL is supposed to be able to support specifying a base DN plus the address and port, but I have tried every format available with no luck. I'm curious how this would work at all without any ability to determine or specify the search base?